# PHP what is faster {$code} or .$code?

Tags: php, benchmarking

I dont know how i can test it.

What is faster in PHP:

```
$test = "Text {$code}";
```

or

```
$test = "Text ".$code;
```

?

Comment: `$test = 'Text ' . $code;`

Comment: @DarrenH  give the reason too,why?

Comment: Honestly there is absolutely no real performance difference. If you're struggling with performance, you're looking at the wrong place to make your code faster.

Comment: Here's a way you can test these out in the future https://eval.in/655121. Notice the difference is less the .1 second after a million iterations.

Comment: That will be usefull, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In the real world, you will never notice any difference, so don't stress about it :)**

It's unlikely you will experience any noticeable speed problems with either of your options, but let me explain the differences anyway and what the quickest solution would be.

When you use double quotes "like this" php will attempt to evaluate any text within the quotes, which is why you can use {$code} within it, you could of course also miss out the curly brackets and simply write "Text $code" unless there is something more complex than a simple variable being evaluated.

Your second example I expect would be marginally slower (I don't have evidence of this, but I suppose we could write a simple test for it if required). As it is first attempting to evaluate the string, THEN concatenating a variable to the string, this is a separate operation.

If speed is your real concern, then use single quotes. The contents of these will never be evaluated, so you can simply take the text string and concatenate the variable.

Like this:

```
$test = 'Text ' . $code
```

Comment: In modern PHP versions there is absolutely little to no performance difference from single to double quotes.

Comment: As a side note, as @Charlotte Dunois pointed out, if you are experiencing performance issues, please post your code as a separate question and we will help figure out what the problem is, because it isn't this!

Answer (score 0):

Your first option is the fastest:

> Benchmarks run against PHP 5.2 and 5.3 show that parsing double-quoted 
>   strings with interpolation is no slower (and often faster) than single- 
>   quoted strings using concatenation. When simple strings with no 
>   variables in them are used, the performance is clearly better with 
>   double-quoted strings due to implementation details in the engine.

Reference [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/make-the-web-faster/3fvoLdgECMw)

Comment: In modern PHP versions there is absolutely little to no performance difference from single to double quotes.

Comment: I followed the link and was looking forward to seeing the benchmarks, but postie.org is spitting out 503 errors. Do you have the benchmarks posted anywhere else?